# AWS API Gateway Always Pass Same Authentication Header

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway to wrap around an existing web service. The web service does not allow anonymous access to GET functions as it is written. Thus, using API Gateway, I want to do the following:

Take all GET requests and add a header in the form of Authentication: Basic (base64 encoded authentication). All non-GET requests (POST, etc.) should not have the header.

I can figure out how to add a header to the request, but not the contents of the header, as I do not want it to passed in by the user. Here is what I am looking at:

[image: API Gateway Screenshot]

How do I make it always pass the authentication header for anonymous access?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your [integration request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters) such that the Authorization header is set to a static value or some other mapped value.